# Android Pass value to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a `MainActivity` with 30 buttons (Ids: `imageButton1`,`imageButton2`...). On the click event, I'm starting a new activity called `KlikNaDugme`:

**MainActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    buttons = new ImageButton[30];

    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton + i);
        vr = i;
        buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, KlikNaDugme.class).putExtra("vrijednost", vr);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I'm trying to pass `vr` to the `KlikNaDugme` activity, which is declared as a `public int`.

**KlikNaDugme Activity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_klik_na_dugme);

    int x = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("vrijednost");
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

**The problem is that it always gets a value of 29. How can I pass the id correctly?**

Comment: I guess your findViewById(R.id.imageButton + i) is not correct. take a look at this:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227310/how-can-we-use-a-variable-in-r-id)

Comment: What are the names of the buttons?

Comment: @MohammadRezaKhahani you are right there is a problem. mTak you mean Ids? It goes from 1 to 30 in this format "@+id/imageButton1", "@+id/imageButton2"....

Comment: @markelof see my edited answer, where I fix the ids problem

Comment: @markelof did you try my answer?

Comment: Take a look at edited answer. When user click on ImageButtons the value of vr is 29 because it is the last value you assign to it. So any ImageButton you click you will get that value.

Comment: @mTak It works. Thank you!

Comment: @markelof I'm glad

Comment: @MohammadRezaKhahani many thanks. You guys are amazing. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the value of `i` in the button's tag:

```
    buttons = new ImageButton[30];

    for(int i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
        {
            buttons[i] = (ImageButton) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("imageButton" + (i + 1), "id", this.getPackageName()));
            buttons[i].setTag(i);

            buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, KlikNaDugme.class)
                    myIntent.putExtra("vrijednost", Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString()));
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: nice and clean.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here:

```
buttons[i] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton + i);
```

What you are doing is that you're creating an **invalid resource reference** and then finding your view upon that reference, which is obviously wrong. Remember `findViewById()` needs a resource id which is generated by Android Studio itself.

**The solution is to save all of your 20-30 views references in an array and then use a loop to set click listeners on them**

Answer (score 0):

Add the vr value as tag to button and then use getTag() method to get the vr value inside onclicklistener

```
            for(int i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
            {
                buttons[i] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton + i);
                vr = i;
                buttons[i].setTag(vr); // This will se the vr value as tag
                buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        int vr = (int)view.getTag()  // this will get the vr value from view
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                                KlikNaDugme.class).putExtra("vrijednost", vr);
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

R.id.what_ever will give you an integer value that generated by android studio in R class not the what_ever string. You should use `getResources().getIdentifier()` to get correct id of resource and pass it to `findViewById()`.

Please try this code. It will get you the correct id of ImageButtons:

```
    buttons = new ImageButton[30];

    for(int i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
        {
            String buttonID = "imageButton" + (i+1);
            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", getPackageName());

            buttons[i] = (ImageButton) findViewById(resID);
            buttons[i].setTag(i);
            //vr = i;
            buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View args0) {

                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                            KlikNaDugme.class).putExtra("vrijednost", (int)args0.getTag());
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            });
        }
```

Enjoy it.